How to use convert to subdirectory for element of hash?
I have a webapp consisting which has an index.html and main.js. When you put in the url:
https://{domain}/{directory}

it loads index.html and runs the script, as you'd expect.
I have implemented some additional functionality based on the hash. Such as:
https://{domain}/{directory}#mode={mode}&arg1=value&arg2=value

But I'd like to change this url to:
https://{domain}/{directory}/mode#arg1=value&arg2=value

Ideally without duplicating most of the main index.html.
How can I achieve this?
As a secondary stretch goal I'd to look at having the window.location.url reflect the current mode, so:
if you navigate to https://{domain}/{directory}/ it would change to:
https://{domain}/{directory}/mode

And if you change mode this would change to reflect it.
I've been playing with using <meta http-equiv=/> but this doesn't seem to be the right approach, and I was also considering using iframe but that also doesn't really seem to be the right solution.
Thanks

I've been playing with using but this doesn't seem to - what? using what? please note, you seem to think you use \ in URL's ... no ... you use / ... some of your question is not clear maybe because you are using \ instead of / and it's hiding characters

nevermind - I fixed the readability of your question ... can you explain what this has to do with javascript?

If you don't want to create an actual file or folder for each "mode" - then you need to start by looking into server-side URL rewriting.

There's nothing to stop me creating a separate subdirectory and index.html if that's the correct/only non-server based solution. I was hoping there would be some other simple way to do it, that I had missed. I also hadn't understood it would not be possible to share js global context between different subdirectory bits of URL.

Remember that the hash isn't sent to the server, it's processed only on the client. The default action is to scroll to the element with that name or id, but client-side JavaScript can override this. But it doesn't change which page is loaded.
